# node.js fs.readFile not working in Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

Right now I am on an XP box, but this is the same thing on Vista.

I am using node.js v 0.6.14

the following does not work:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function(err, data) { ... } );
```

I do NOT get anything in err, but data contains the following:

> '{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I remove the encoding parameter, then I do get the raw buffer data back.  Is this a known issue on the Windows port of node or am I completely missing something?  If it is a known issue, are there any good workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of file is it? I created a text file named "text.txt" with the contents of "this is a text file".

I don't have an XP VM handy, but this worked fine for me in node 0.6.9:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("text.txt","utf8",function(err,data){
    console.log("err: " + err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

with output of:

```
err: null
this is a text file
```

Comment: HTML5. Nothing special.  What OS were you using?  I will try a text file and see what happens.

Comment: Mine also worked with text.txt... curiouser and curiouser.  Now, I did have my text.txt file in the same directory where I was running node. Next thing I will try is moving the html file I was trying to process into the same directory and see if that works.

Comment: Yep. That works too.  So, must be something about the paths I am using to reference the files.

Comment: Now, it is working at the other location too??  Back to the drawing board, I think.  I think I have bigger problems.  I am going to close this question.  Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Well, I "would" close it, but I am not worthy :)

Comment: @MarkLybrand mind accepting my answer since it pointed you in the right direction? :)