# Getting error while reading local file in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-io, npm

I am trying to read a local file using node.js. My NPM module is trying to execute a child process and that inturn opens a file to read. While reading this throws an error

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'E:\Project\SecIntegrator\Attack\manifest.json']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'E:\\Project\\SecIntegrator\\Attack\\manifest.json' }
```

Actual path to read this file is

```
E:\Project\SecIntegrator\node_modules\restScannerDriver\GarudRudra\Attack\manifest.json
```

I have used var `configPath = path.join(path.dirname(fs.realpathSync(__filename)), '/');` to calculate absolute path but still not working.

Comment: Which method for reading did you use?

Comment: `file.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err,data) {}`

Comment: Not sure but your path looks like a Windows path so have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015877/node-js-fs-readfile-not-working-in-windows

Comment: If I run code from different command prompt as a standalone code, it works fine. When I integrate it as NPM module, it is not able to take path properly.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the NPM module your path changes.
So try to use __dirname in NPM and create the realpath like that:

```
var filepath = fs.realpathSync(__dirname+'/'+relative path from here to your file);
```

After that look what's the result of filepath